# Laravel eloquent model where datetime less than or equal

Tags: laravel-5

I am having an expire_datetime field in Test model and it has many relationship with Candidate model. I want to get all the tests which exipre_datetime is less than or equeal to now datetime. I am doing like this but I am getting all the records, date comparirion is not functioning.

**Test Model:**

```php
    public function testcandidates()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Candidate::class,'test_id','id');
    }
```

**TestController:**

```php
$tests = Test::with([
            'testcandidates' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('result', '=', 'assigned');
             }
         ])
         ->where('expire_datetime', '<=', Carbon::now('UTC'))
         ->get();
```

Comment: Did you add expire_datetime as a date to `protected $dates` in your model ?

Comment: No, I did not. I will try this.

Comment: This is working. Actually, the DateTime was wrongly stored in DB and was not getting correct records. Datetime was string type in DB which I changed to timestamp and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get string from carbon: `Carbon::now('UTC')->toDateTimeString()`

```
$tests = Test::with(
   ['testcandidates' => function ($query) {
       $query->where('result', '=', 'assigned');
    }])
    ->where('expire_datetime', '<=', Carbon::now('UTC')->toDateTimeString())
    ->get();
```